# How to extract only 'Day' value from full 'Date' string?

Tags: php, date

I have an array of Date values in the format of `'Y-m-d'`. I want to loop over the array and only extract the day (`'d'`) of each member, but can't figure out to split it. Do I use substrings in some way?

Put simply, I have `'2010-11-24'`, and I want to get just `'24'` from that. The problem being the day could be either single or double figures.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you have PHP < 5.3, use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$string = "2010-11-24";
$timestamp = strtotime($string);
echo date("d", $timestamp);
```

If you have PHP >= 5.3, use a `DateTime` based solution using [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) - `DateTime` is the future and can deal with dates beyond 1900 and 2038:

```
 $string = "2010-11-24";
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $string);
 echo $date->format("d");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$date = '2010-11-24';
list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $date);
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/cbZv1), docs on [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Or even

```
$date = '2010-11-24';
$d = substr($date, strrpos($date, '-') + 1);
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/6yXGK), docs on [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).

*Disclaimer: Both are oldschool!*

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`date_parse_from_format`](http://php.net/date_parse_from_format), e.g.:

```
date_parse_from_format('Y-m-d', '2010-11-24')['day'];
```

---

Testing in shell:

```
$ php -r "echo date_parse_from_format('Y-m-d', '2010-11-24')['day'];"
24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php> $d = '2010-11-24';
'2010-11-24'
php> $fields = explode('-', $d);
array (
  0 => '2010',
  1 => '11',
  2 => '24',
)
php> $fields[2];
'24'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$dates = array('2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-23');

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $day[] = substr($date, 8, 2);
}

var_dump($day);

?>
```

Comment: Depends on whether month could be just `9` or will always be `09`, though.

Comment: If I understood what you were asking correctly that will give you just the day part of the date.

Comment: In the format suggested Y-m-d, m will have leading zeros in the case of a month less than 10 so 01, 02, 03 etc....

Comment: @martswite I was just noting that OP stated that "The problem being the day could be either single or double figures." The same *may* be the case for the month. I don't know.

Comment: @jensgram thats fair enough, I saw the format and went into overdrive. I'm new to this helping out malarky. Pretty interesting to see the way everyone else rolls.

Comment: Any solution for no leading zeros?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "2010-11-24";
$date = new DateTime($string);
echo date_format($date, 'd');
```

Answer (score -1):

$dt = "2008/02/23";

echo 'The day is '. date("d", strtotime($dt));