# Getting time and date from timestamp with php

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

In my database I have a time stamp column...which reflects a format like this: 2012-04-02 02:57:54

However I would like to separate them up into `$date` and `$time`.

After some research through the php manual...I found that `date()`, `date_format()` and `strtotime()` are able to help me to separate them...(not sure if I am right)

But I am not very sure of how to code it out...

In my php file...the timestamp extracted would be `$row['DATETIMEAPP']`.

Will

```
$date = strtotime('d-m-Y',$row['DATETIMEAPP']);
$time = strtotime('Gi.s',$row['DATETIMEAPP']);
```

or

```
$date = date('d-m-Y',$row['DATETIMEAPP']);
```

work?

Can I use `date()` to get the time as well??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this question not useful?? just wanna know which is best way to get the 2 value out from timestamp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract only 'Day' value from full 'Date' string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275599/how-to-extract-only-day-value-from-full-date-string)

Comment: i can't try because i have other errors on the page...i want to know if this plays a part in causing the error...Thanks

Comment: @deceze i thought that was to convert a date to time stamp?

Comment: No, that's one example of how to extract the DD part of a YYYY-MM-DD date string. And many similar such questions have been posted many times already.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row['DATETIMEAPP']);
```

gives you timestamp, which then you can use date to format:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
$time = date('Gi.s', $timestamp);
```

Alternatively

```
list($date, $time) = explode('|', date('d-m-Y|Gi.s', $timestamp));
```

Comment: This is the best and easy answer. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 10):

If you dont want to change the format of date and time from the timestamp, you can use the `explode` function in php

```
$timestamp = "2012-04-02 02:57:54"
$datetime = explode(" ",$timestamp);
$date = $datetime[0];
$time = $datetime[1];
```

Comment: list($date,$time)=explode(' ','2014-11-21 16:38:00');

Answer (score 2):

```
$mydatetime = "2012-04-02 02:57:54";
$datetimearray = explode(" ", $mydatetime);
$date = $datetimearray[0];
$time = $datetimearray[1];
$reformatted_date = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date));
$reformatted_time = date('Gi.s',strtotime($time));
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this:**

For Date:

```
$date = new DateTime($from_date);
$date = $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

For Time:

```
$time = new DateTime($from_date);
$time = $time->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp='2014-11-21 16:38:00';

list($date,$time)=explode(' ',$timestamp);
```

// just time

```
preg_match("/ (\d\d:\d\d):\d\d$/",$timestamp,$match);
echo "\n<br>".$match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
select DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( columnname ) ) from tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, you can do so like this:

```
$timestamp = $row['DATETIMEAPP']; // String formatted as "2012-04-02 02:57:54"

// Create DateTime object from custom timestamp
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);

$date = $dt->format('d-m-Y'); // String variable of just the date
$time = $dt->format('H:i:s'); // String variable of just the time
```

And if you're concerned about using `DateTime` over `strtotime()` or `date()`, I'd like to point you in the direction of [this conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605563/datetime-class-vs-native-php-date-functions) on StackOverflow titled "DateTime class vs. native PHP date-functions."

Answer (score -1):

Optionally you can use database function for date/time formatting. For example in MySQL query use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATETIMEAPP,'%d-%m-%Y') AS date, DATE_FORMT(DATETIMEAPP,'%H:%i:%s') AS time FROM yourtable
```

I think that over databases provides solutions for date formatting too