# php convert date formats

Tags: php, date, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting time and date from timestamp with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970584/getting-time-and-date-from-timestamp-with-php)

I am trying to convert this date format:

```
09/14/2012 10:11
```

into this other standard timestamp format:

```
2012-09-14 09:44:54
```

What is the most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of the right side and search function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](http://es.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object

```
$date = DateTime($myDate);
```

or your custom input format with [createFromFormat](http://es.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y H:i:s', $myDate);
```

[format](http://es.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) Will make your output

```
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP's [`date`](http://php.net/date) and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) functions:

```
$date = '09/14/2012 10:11';
$formatted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('09/14/2012 10:11'));
```

Though it's going to be hard to change the time.

Answer (score 1):

Convert first into timestamp with `strtotime` and convert timestamp into date with `date`.

```
$outputDate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $inputDate ));
```